# ARKit 2 issue with light inside box

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, ios12

I have an ARScene view that i add a big box (SCNNode) that has images on the inside "walls".

In phones with ios versions lower that 12 it works perfectly and I can see the images in the walls. In phones with ios version >= 12 I see the inside of the box white.

The box is being added correctly because when I change the opacity of the SCNNode I can see the pictures but it's behind a white layer.

I think that it's a lighting issue because no light passes the box and that's why I get the white "walls".

Does anyone know which property do I have to change to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

> Wait for the official release of iOS 12.1. Now iOS 12.1 is beta and some bugs happen.

```
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    // use the features available in iOS 12.0
} else {
    // or just use some workaround
}
```

At the moment officially working release is iOS 12.0 (16A366).

Comment: It has the same issue in ios 12